# Database code no longer works

Tags: sql-server, database

I am having trouble the this bit of code.

```
string sqlCon = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;" +
                @"AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ChessDatabase.mdf;
                  Integrated Security=True;
                  Connect Timeout=30;
                  User Instance=True";
SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(sqlCon);
Con.Open();
```

This same bit of code worked succesfully once before.
It was used to add records to the data to a database.  Now the error says that it can’t open the data base because it is already open.

Any Ideas?  What other information do you need that might be helpful?

Comment: If the error says the connection is already open, you don't need to connect again, you can go ahead and run your query. You should close the connection to your database after the query, then re-open it before the next query.

Comment: You probably opened the connection to same database by using Server explorer. Close the connection in server explorer and it should work.

Comment: Primary information that's needed is the particular DBMS (MS SQL Server?) that you're using, and maybe the language you're coding in.  If it worked before and doesn't work now, something changed — what?  Because there's a decent chance that breakage is a result of that change.  Or, if not that change, then another change at about the same time.

Comment: Looks like the connection is closed to start with.  Here is the error
  Message=Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'DanielWebb-PC\Daniel Webb'.
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
This does not help me much  I think It is the database that has changed, and it is not the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
string sqlCon = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;" +
                @"AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ChessDatabase.mdf;
                  Integrated Security=True;
                  Connect Timeout=30;
                  User Instance=True";
SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(sqlCon);
            if (Con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                 Con.Open();
            }
```

Before open the connection check whether connection is already opened or closed.

Comment: Although I agree with your answer it is would also be important for the OP to find out the database is already unexpectedly opened. In general you do not want to have connections flying around ;)

Comment: Looks like the connection is closed to start with.  Here is the error
  Message=Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'DanielWebb-PC\Daniel Webb'.
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider

Comment: I  have tried the above code and it don not help.  Looks like the connection is closed to start with.  Here is the error
  Message=Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'DanielWebb-PC\Daniel Webb'.
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider.  
I do have a smaller program that uses the same code, but it only works with an early version of the database.  When the little program is used with any other database, I get an error like this.

The database ……..  cannot be opened because it is version 706.  This server supports version 655 and earlier